# How to activate python environment in ZSH using VSCode terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a folder called `src` where there is a python environment called `venv`.

When `src` is open in VSCode, I need this environment to be activated as soon as I launch a terminal.

In `src/.vscode/settings.json` I have set

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
```

Which correctly activates `venv` when `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux` is set to `bash`. However when it is set to `zsh`, the python interpreter used is the global one (`/usr/bin/python3`) and I have to manually run `source venv/bin/activate` in the terminal so that it uses `src/venv/bin/python3` instead.

I also tried the following:

```json
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "venv": {
      "path": "/bin/zsh", // works with "/bin/bash" 
      "source": "venv/bin/activate",
      "args": []
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "venv"
```

But I get the same result.

In this folder, zsh always puts this at the end of the line
[image]. I am not sure what this means exactly but I suspect it could give a clue of what's happening.

I also tried disabling all my zsh plugins but again, same result.

Comment: `However when it is set to zsh, the python interpreter used is the global one`. What does it mean? Please describe your problem in detail, what are your expected and realistic results? What are the gaps. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have no idea what `bin/activate` exactly is doing, if I had this problem, I would for debugging put `-x` into the `args`, to get a trace when the shell is started (works with bash and zsh). You will then get a huge trace of the executions (which hopefully also contains a reference to the `activate` script. Then I would compare the two versions. Wher are significant differences? Perhaps you have not configured your zsh startup correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround (inspired from [here](https://superuser.com/a/91898/1243781)). The **-c** argument from zsh allows to run any command at invocation.

Since we can use arguments with `terminal.integrated.profiles.linux`, a simple solution to put in `settings.json` is:

```json
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "venv": {
      "path": "zsh", // works with "bash" too 
      "args": ["-c", "source venv/bin/activate; zsh -i"]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "venv"
```

NB: It is necessary to write `zsh -i` at the end otherwise the zsh terminal closes instantly.